# D3 - word cloud, Chinese text implementation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to visualize a speech that has been transcribed to Chinese text. I tried pointing to the whole text file as well as a simple hard coded text string, but no matter what, I'm getting no errors. For this reason, I am unsure how to troubleshoot further.

```js
var text_string = "CHINESE TEXT HERE";
//word cloud start
    //d3.text('jin-bo-speech.txt', function(text) {

      //var text_string = text;

      drawWordCloud(text_string);

      function drawWordCloud(text_string){

        var word_count = {};

        var words = text_string.split(/[\-\(\)\*":;\[\]|{},.!?]+/);
          if (words.length == 1){
            word_count[words[0]] = 1;
          } else {
            words.forEach(function(word){
              var word = word.toLowerCase();
              if (word != "" && word.length>1){
                if (word_count[word]){
                  word_count[word]++;
                } else {
                  word_count[word] = 1;
                }
              }
            })
          }

        var svg_location = "#chart";
        var width = 1200;
        var height = 600;

        var svg = d3.select('body')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height);

        var fill = d3.scale.linear()
                .range(["#15198e","#adc8f0",'gray']);

        var word_entries = d3.entries(word_count);

        console.log(word_count)

        var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
           .domain([0, d3.max(word_entries, function(d) {
              return d.value;
            })
           ])
           .range([10,100]);

        d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height])
          .timeInterval(20)
          .words(word_entries)
          .fontSize(function(d) { return xScale(+d.value); })
          .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
          .rotate(0)
          .font("Teko")
          .on("end", draw)
          .start();

        function draw(words) {
          d3.select("svg")
            .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + [width >> 1, height >> 1] + ")")
            .selectAll("text")
              .data(words)
            .enter().append("text")
              .style("font-size", function(d) { return xScale(d.value) + "px"; })
              .style("font-family", "Teko")
              .style("fill", 'gray')
              .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
              .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
              })
              .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

d3.layout.cloud().stop();
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
   <script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ericcoopey/6382449/raw/c61e6febb945ca6833089c1d39a5a40bb14d2734/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

What I do notice is that when I hard-code the text in my script, the console log correctly shows the text (see the variable `text_string`). However, despite `text_string` being defined, the word cloud doesn't draw.

### Question

Can anyone with experience with Jason Davies' word cloud share their thoughts on visualizing text in other languages?

**Note:** For accuracy, I tried including actual Chinese text in the snippet, but that impeded my entire post -- I guess there are English-only rules on SE.